# How to block all other actions

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, indexoutofboundsexception

In my app i have a ListView which dynamically increases by adding 10 items everytime on scrolling down. when i click on any item it takes me to a google-map, and to get back to the listView i have a button.

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MapMarkerActivity.this,
                    FeedListViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

but my FeedListViewActivity takes some 3-4 secs to load , so during this time if i click the back button on my device the screen flashes for some 0.3 sec and show the google-map(essentially its not going anywhere). now i click the back button on my device it gives me a blank screen and when i click the back button second time it takes me to the listView. the problem is here...now when i try to scroll the listview my app crashes saying:

IndexOutOfBounf index=30 size=10;

so i changed my onclick to:

```
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
```

now on clicking this button it gives me a blank screen and then i must click the back button of my device to get to the listview from the google-map.

My question is why am i getting that blank screen... I mean why should i click twice back to get back to the listview and why am i getting the indexOutOfBound exception.

The reason i named the question this way is "i want that back button on my device to be blocked when i click on the button(in my app) to go back to the listview which has a 3-4 sec delay"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bpgc  if you are coming back from mapview to list view know that time you are used Async task to laod the listview ????

if do you want block back button press event means just use

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: u mean something like "no one must interrupt while loading the listview" ??

Comment: Yeah @ Archie.bpgc . absolutely right.. if you want to go out of your app from list view or mapview use intent instead of pressing backbutton.

Comment: i cant find this onBackPressed() in Override/Implement Methods..:(

Comment: yeah i dont want to use the backbutton but if some user clickx the back button this way my app is getting crashed

Comment: this is override method only. but dont try in oncreate... just put this override method and try. for your satisfaction just put one print statement or Toast and check .. you wont get any action other than that print statement or Toast. no other action will get occur and your app wont get crash .

Comment: no im  using outside onCreate..but still i cant find the method in Override/Implement Methods. If i just copy paste it asks to remove Override notaion and all....

Comment: if you are using android version less than 1.6 means it wont get support that override method. else it will work . for me its working .. and not asking to remove that @override.

Comment: I wrote this in my onBackPressed(){Intent intent = new Intent(MapMarkerActivity.this,
    FeedListViewActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);}

Comment: thats working fine ...thank you...but do you know why i get a blank screen when i click back button of my device when i am on google-map??....i need to click back twice to go back to the previous screen(what ever screen it is)

Comment: this is unwanted one know. you are going to mapactivity from listactivity by startActivity. if you are not added finish(); means this list activity wont get die. from map activity you are pressed back key with out any event means it will automatically redirect to listview . but have one thing in mind it wont restart your list view activity again . it will simply show the list where you have left.

Comment: see the problem is instead of this intent and all in my onBackPressed() method if i write finish(); then it gives me a blank screen and i need to click the back button for the second time....and why i want to use finish(); is...consider a case where user scrolls down to 100th item and clicks on it to go to map and when clicked on back button he must be taked to the 100th item right....not the 1st item which we get using intent

Comment: yeah exactly as u said in your last comment i wanted to use finish();....but it gives me a blank screen

Comment: if you are added the {Intent intent = new Intent(MapMarkerActivity.this, FeedListViewActivity.class); startActivity(intent); these lines in back pressed in mapview means it will recreate the list view activity again . no now you will have two activities with out die . so that only you are getting black screen again.

Comment: using intent i am not getting blank screen...but recreates the listview again....i am getting blank screen when i am using finish(); or clicking the back button (without any onBackPressed() method in my app)

Comment: i need to click the back button twice to get to the listview if i am using finish();

Comment: you should use like  these. 

     1. from list view to map view. 

             {Intent intent = new Intent(listview .this, mapview.class); startActivity(intent); finish();

     2. from mapview to list view 
     
            {Intent intent = new Intent(mapview .this, listview.class); startActivity(intent); finish();

     3. else should not add finish(); from list view to mapview. add the finish(); alone in mapview back pressed.

Comment: if you will post your list view and mapview code alone her means i will solve that issue.

Comment: see the actual problem is....user is on 100th item and then he goes to someother Xactivity by clicking some button....now from that Xactivity he clicks a button named "feed" to get back to the listview which takes 4 secs....during this 4 secs if he clicks the back button of the device....it gets back to the Xactivity....now when i click on the back button it tries to show the 100th item on the listView but the listView has only 10 items because its recreated...thats why...IndexOutOfBounds error....index = 99 size = 10....can u help solving this??

Comment: no not exactly the Index but the ArrayList which i use to add data to the list view is static

Comment: could me post atleast the line which you are getting indexbounds of exception. So that i will tel you the good solution.

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime(26621): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131099739, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.Android.WiC_MobileApp.Adapter.LazyAdapter)]

Comment: my listview must load images from server, hence i am using a background thread....but is the background thread which is specified in the error is the same background thread i am using to load images??